Is ATL-98 Carvair still alive in the US?
Is ATL-98 still operative or at least displayed within the U.S.?
According to Wikipedia, N89FA is based in Gainesville, Texas, at KGLE, but is it true?
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aviation_Traders_Carvair


A total of 21 DC-4 were converted to ATL-98. According to articles, the three last flying airframes have been:

N898AT: Destructed in an accident in 2007.

9J-PAA: Not operative. Most recent picture in March 2022. De-registered from Zambian register and many sites add it has been scrapped, supposedly since the picture was taken.

N89FA: Not operative according to CNN, likely correct but to be confirmed. Currently registered by South African Air Lease, with an expiration date in 2028. Most recent picture shot in April 2024.


As of today, no ATL-98 is supposed to fly. N89FA, which registration is valid until 2028, is visible on Google Maps (aerial view dated 2024), but is not visible on Bing Maps (aerial view is not dated precisely).
It's likely possible to get better data, I'm posting this only as a basis to start with.

References
CNN, in 2021:

As of 2021, no Carvair is known to be operative, although a couple of airframes are in long term storage. Their airworthiness status is uncertain.



One of them is in Gainesville, Texas, where it has been parked at the local airport for a number of years.




The other belongs to Phoebus Apollo Aviation, a South African pilot training school, based at Rand airport in the outskirts of Johannesburg.


Mentour Pilot, in 2021:

The last ATL-98 Carvair to fly was written-off after a crash-landing in 2007, in Alaska.


Here’s a picture of N89FA that I took on September 16, 2024 at the Gainesville, Texas airport .

Does it work and fly

Looks in the same condition as in April, deflated tires, peeling rudder paint, and rudder slightly deflected by the same angle.
